# Texture2D text color changed after updating from iOS 3.0 to 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, texture2d

I'm using an OpenGL Texture2D class and initWithString method to display strings to the user.  When running with iOS 3.0 and XCode 3.1.3 all the text would appear black in the simulator and white on the phone.  After updating to iOS 4.0, XCode 3.2.3, and iPhone SDK 4.0 the text appears black on the phone!  Not so good since my app is almost complete and the artwork was designed around white text.  How can I fix this?

More info:  I'm testing on a 3G phone.  Also the texture2D class is from Crashlanding.

Comment: What color did the text appear on SGX-based devices (e.g. iPhone 3GS, 3rd-gen iPod touch)? Also, are you using the standard texture environment modes or configuring your own custom texture combiner state?

Comment: I've only tested on the 3G.  I'm not sure regarding your second question (new to OpenGL ES and OpenGL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution with some **awesome** help provided by [this blog](http://majicjungle.com/blog/?p=191) (majicjungle.com).  Basically I modified the Texture2D class initWithString method as mentioned in the first few steps of the linked tutorial.

Here are the modifications I made:

1)  Replaced four lines in initWithString w/ these four lines:

```
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
data = calloc(1, width * height * 4);
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, width * 4, colorSpace,          kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

2)  Replaced 
    kTexture2DPixelFormat_A8 
with 
    kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888 
in the call to initWithData

3)  Changed 
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0); 
to
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

The 2nd-4th arguments to CGContextSetRGBFillColor are the RGB values.  Making them all 1.0 resulted in the desired white font color.

I definitely advise reading the blog post... it's very helpful.